# Swagger-ui in Dart

Tags: dart, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Dart, and i want to implements swagger-ui, as a web on my proyect.
I have the json/yaml file of my API and that API running on local.
The JS+Css+Html Option of swagger-ui works fine, but, is there a way to generate a web like this in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am confused what you want to do.

Dart has it's own documentation generator, `dartdoc`, that works out of the box for any package. I don't know of any support for swagger or if it offers any particular advantages for Dart users.

An example for `args` package:
https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/args/0.13.7/index.html

Comment: I use to use JavaScript with swagger-ui to make my Swagger WebApi visible.
Now, i'm working with Dart and AngularDart, and trying to avoid js code.
So i was wondering me if, like there is an JS+css ui Swagger, there is some AngulartDart version or some way to do it like i was doing with swagger-ui (js+css, standalone and reading a json).